# Do you know any open/standard resume format?

Tags: data-format, standards

I would like to know if there is any kind open/standard resume or Curriculum Viate format which allows interchanging of resumes between systems.

Any hint?

Comment: You'd think that at the very least the 'publications' portion could be transfered using [BibTeX](http://www.bibtex.org/).  It might also be possible to use [micro formats](http://microformats.org/) to mark up portions of the CV.

Comment: @joe is onto something...i use microformats for mine...as long as you are dealing with web technology, its the best bet

Comment: Unfortunately with todays recruitment industry the way it is, if you make your c.v. highly discoverable… you'll probably regret it!

Comment: @HarryWood I think one thing is the **format** you use to share stuff and other thing is how much you share (**privacy policy** or alike). From my point of view there are pretty unrelated, though I understand your corncern about sharing your personal info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ResumeRDF](http://rdfs.org/resume-rdf/) seems to be the most "ontological" approach to normalization of CV information. The W3C has another [article about ResumeRDF](http://www.w3.org/wiki/ResumeRDFOntology) with further links.

Answer (score 2):

i guess this is an old question, but there is HR-XML now. http://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/hr-xml/2007-04-15/

Answer (score 2):

[h-resume](http://microformats.org/wiki/h-resume) (formally hresume) is a simple, open format for publishing resumes and CVs on on the web. h-resume is one of several open microformat draft standards suitable for embedding data in HTML.
h-resume is the microformats2 version of hresume.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the EU [Europass](https://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/) project.

CVs can be saved out in a Europass XML format.